# why the prototype of an object which created by new Object() is undefined?

Tags: javascript

Chrome just logs `undefined` with this following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><body><script>

var cody = new Object();

console.log(cody.prototype);

</script></body></html>
```

and I think it should be `Object.prototype`, but now it is `undefined`, why?

I try `for (var p in cody){console.log(p);}` but just got nothing.

Answer (score 2):

It's the *constructor function* (`Object` in this case) that has a `prototype` property. An actual *instance* gets a reference to the prototype in [the `__proto__` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto):

```
var cody = new Object();
console.log(cody.__proto__ === Object.prototype);
// => true
```

Note that this is **not standardized**. From the MDN docs:

> This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future.

In modern browsers you <strike>can also</strike> *should* use [`Object.getPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf):

```
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(cody) === Object.prototype);
// => true
```

Comment: Or `Object.getPrototypeOf(cody)`.

Comment: thanks for your answer but why can't I enumerate the __proto__ out by for(var p in cody){console.log(p);}?

Comment: @igonejack: Some properties (such as `__proto__`) are not enumerable: http://zduck.com/2013/non-enumerable-properties-in-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

`prototype` is a special property functions have that gets assigned as [[Prototype]] (notice the difference) of newly created objects. To get the [[Prototype]] value you can do:

```
var cody = new Object();
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(cody)); // Object {}
```

In other words, the prototype is undefined because cody is not a function. The object cody inherits its properties from is it's internal [[Prototype]] property which is inaccessible by 'normal' means.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf